# Integração Windows form com página html

Tags: c#, html, winforms

Eu tenho uma aplicação que é um Windows Forms que eu preciso integrar em uma página HTML da minha aplicação web

No caso fazer com que o Windows Form fique ali fixo como se os dois fossem uma coisa só.

Isto é possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Usando apenas Html não é possível.**

Você pode incluir na sua página Html aplicativos desenvolvidos com *Flash* e *Silverlight*, por exemplo.

Houve tempo em que era muito comum incluir também componentes *ActiveX* (que podem ser desenvolvidos em qualquer linguagem) ou Java *applets*; mas este tipo de recurso é um risco em potencial para o usuário então há uma tendência de não serem mais suportados ou terem o seu uso dificultado pelos navegadores.

Há opções que fazem parecer que o aplicativo está rodando dentro do Browser, como o *Citrix*, mas o aplicativo não estará embutido em uma página Html.

Comment: Com Websockets teria alguma solução?

Comment: @Lorena O que eu conheço por *Websockets* é comunicação por rede. Não parece estar relacionado.

Comment: é exatamente isto que preciso, não precisa estar embutido mas parecer que está, não vai ter troca de dados entre a página html e o software externo, só preciso fazer com que o usuário veja os dois juntos como se fossem apenas um.

Comment: @Lorena Não dá não. A página web teria que mandar o browser consumir este aplicativo externo, o qual o browser não tem como saber se é seguro ou não. O browser precisa limitar o máximo possível o acesso de uma página web à máquina do usuário; a idéia é tornar segura a navegação web mesmo que o usuário não conheça previamente a idoneidade do link que ele vai clicar.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia botar um WebBrowser na sua form, em seguda botar no código:

```
 [nome do webbrowser].DocumentText = "Código HTML em string";
ou [nome do webbrowser].Navegate("url da página HTML ou caminho no computador");
```

Você poderia usar o DocumentText do webbrowser para interagir, modificar o código HTML ou ler o código, e asim interagir